# views/routes do not load in docker but in nodejs

Tags: javascript, docker, routes, dockerfile

We made a web-app with different views in pug. In nodejs everything works totally fine but after creating a docker image and starting the website with docker, only the index loads.

The "upload" view does not appear at all

[image: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYTMd.png)]

the "Karte" view does work but it won't load the leaflet map.

Here is the app.js where I define the views

```
// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/upload", uploadRouter);
app.use("/karte", karteRouter);
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
    appservice: 
        container_name: AppGeosoft2
        #build: .
        image: felioxx/geosoft2image
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        command: npm start ##
        ports: 
            - '3000:3000'
        depends_on: 
            - mongoservice
    mongoservice:
        container_name: mongo 
        image: mongo # image retrieved from docker hub
        ports:
            - '27017:27017'
        volumes:
            - ./mongo-init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
            #- ./mongo-volume:/data/db
    mongoexpressservice: 
        image: mongo-express # image retrieved from docker hub
        restart: always
        ports: 
            - '8081:8081'
        depends_on: 
            - mongoservice
```

and the docker file

```
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy app code source from our local folder into the docker /usr/src/app working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy app code sour /package.json
COPY . .

# Expose app on a given port
EXPOSE 3000

# Start app
CMD node server.js
```

and here is the folder structure:

[image: [work directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjpQr.png)]

I'm so confused cause it works totally fine in nodejs and when I google the error the threads only apply to nodejs and not docker.

I suspect the error comes from the settings of the work directory (that's what it's saying lol) but I don't really know where to change the path where docker is looking.

Comment: Did you check if the view is available inside the docker container? Whats the output of `ls /usr/src/app/views` inside the container ?
You can also use `docker exec -it containerName ls /usr/src/app/views`

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Apparently it was a typo lol. I wrote the U in Upload in upper case. Seems like node isn't case sensitive but docker is